# discord.js reduce message.content to 1024 char

Tags: node.js, embed, discord.js

how can i reduce message.content to below 1024 char 
my code is like this in messageDelete  event is

```
module.exports = async (client, channel ) => {
    var log = channel.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('member-log')) ;
 var sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setTitle(`:warning: A Message Was Deleted!`)
                .setDescription(`**USER**\n<@${message.author.id}>`)
                .addField(`**Content**`,` \`\`\`${message.content}\`\`\` `)
                .addField(`**Channel**`,`<#${message.channel.id}> (${message.channel.id})`)
                .setFooter(``)
                .setFooter(`MessageID:${message.author.lastMessageID} | AuthorID:${message.author.id}`);
                log.send(sEmbed);
```

error RichEmbed() cannot send more than 1024 char

Comment: can you show the value of `message.content`?

Comment: this is an event so message,content can be anything not that matters if the content  exceeds 1024 char in RichEmbed then its throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
var msg;
// if the message length is more than 1023 characters
if (message.content.length >= 1023) {
    // split the content into an array
    msg = message.content.split(); // ['more than 1023 characters'] 
} else {
    // else just assign the content to the msg variable
    msg = message.content;
}
console.log(msg || msg[0])
```